# Has anyone encountered this error before? How to debug it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Intro.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Can you please tell what actually is happening and how to debug too?

Comment: probably unrelated, but `"http:/https://stackoverflow.com/"`? Something feels wrong with this url...

Comment: The obvious question... does `r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"` exist?